# Where can I find EVOC 20 vocoder of 1990s?

Tags: logic-pro, vocoder

I know the vocoder was firstly developed by the company Emagic, which then bought by Apple. Now it is part of Logic Pro X and impossible to find the original version, that can work in Windows.

Does anyone still have the version of EVOC 20 that was released in the 90s?

Comment: Good luck with that - not only is it 18 years old & likely won't run on anything newer than WInXP, but it's also protected by a software key registration process… obtainable by email from EMagic… who no longer exist. https://www.deepsonic.ch/deep/docs_manuals/emagic_evoc20_v.1.0_manual.pdf

Comment: @Tetsujin OS I need it for their legacy Text-to-speech system which includes some voices I cannot find in the current versions. Do you know where should I search it?

Comment: You might try on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ Those guys seem to have links to all kinds of old stuff.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks. I have posted the question there too.